# Colorchange of metaballs or surface

Tags: shaders

Hello my fellow Blenderians,

I stuck on a project and maybe you can end my struggle. :-)

I made a filament with metaballs (it is more likely a sausage, see the attached pic) and over 100 frames some parts of it increase the volume. Now I tried to achieve a color change for the thick parts. Basically, the idea is: slim metaballs should be blue and big metaballs should be red. (The gradient of color is indicated below the metball-sausage).

I read about metaball families, and that these are always with one material associated. Is there a way to calculate it to a surface and make a colorchange via texture?

Sadly, I haven't found a tutorial which covers that.

Greetings and best regards,
Patrick
[image: colorchange]

Comment: Cycles, Eevee, Workbench or internal render engine.

Comment: I work with Eevee at the moment, but I am also familiar with cycles. I played around with coloring the faces manually, but the transition of the colors is isntant and not smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a gradient on separate object with no UV map, by using texture coordinates.
If we use the texture coordinates of another object (like an *Empty*), we can easily control the position of colors by translating, rotating or scaling the empty.
[image]

Add an *Empty* at the location you want a color change.
In the material of the meta-ball-object, add *Texture Coordinate* node with the *Empty* selected as the *Object*. Separate the Object coordinates and use the first output, the X coordinate. (Adjust this to your objects orientation obviously.) Since we only want the absolute distance on X and not the signed coordinates, add a math node *Absolute* resulting in values >= 0.
[image: object texture coordinate]

By transforming the empty, we can move and scale the gradient.

To be able to be able to influence the overall strength of the gradient, let's use the objects Z position. To get the same value for all position on our meta-object, subtract our Geometry's position from the *Empty*'s position. I concatenated an Add operation, to offset the 0 position. By moving the empty along its Z axis, we can control a single value.

[image: other texture coordinate]

Combine both results with a multiply operation and use this output as the factor between your desired colors.

[image: node_setup]

The resulting material can be controled using the empty. By moving it along the Z axis we control the overall intensity of the second color, and by moving and scaling the X axis we control the transformation of the gradient.

[image: result]

---

If you want to alter the transition you can use

- rgb curves
  [image: rgb curves]
- or a color ramp.
  [image: colorramp]

Answer (score 0):

Convert your metaball object to mesh. Then apply Remesh modifier in smooth mode followed by SubdivSurface steps 2 for good topology. Apply materials the way you want it. Below is an example.

[image]